# Ruby on Rails order a parent model by child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How would I go about doing this? I would like to sort a selection parent model by an attribute on it's children. The parent model has a has many relationship with it's child. I'm not sure how to form the ActiveRecord query to get this.

Example: A thread has many posts. I want to grab a collection of threads ordered by the most recent post associated with it.

I've found a few solutions that convert the selection to an array and do a sort on that array, but I need the selection to stay as an ActiveRecord selection, so I can continue to chain queries onto it.

Answer (score 5):

I would need more information about the layout of your database to give a better example, but you can join another table and then order by that table like so:

```
Thread.joins(:posts).order("posts.created_at").group("threads.id")
```

Comment: The relation between the parent and child is a simple has many relationship.

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR: column "threads.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 5):

For your example, it would be far more efficient to simply have the children touch the parent:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thread,
        touch: true
end
```

This will change Thread's updated_at column whenever a post is created or changed, so that thread is considered updated at that time. You may need to actually access the child records in a more complicated example, but for ordering by the date of the child posts this saves you having to get the extra records out of the database when you don't actually need information from that table.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The actual context is actually a little more complex than my example. 

I'm actually doing what you suggested right now, but the issue arises when I update an attribute specific to Thread, but I want to sort by the most recent Post. Basically I want the most recent Post to take precedence, rather than sorting by the updated_at attribute.

Comment: @followfung you should have accepted this answer. I understand that your context is more complex, but DVG invested relevant amount of time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

By using just plain queries, with no direct iteration over arrays, you can do something like:

```
Post.joins(:thread).includes(:thread).order("posts.created_at").group("thread_id").take(5) 
# Maybe you can take only a few samples of your collection to show on Last Posted Topics, 
# then you just replace take(5) with the number of posts you want to take.
```

Comment: Then you can call ```.map(&:thread).uniq``` at the end of the code posted